# Merging values from separate dictionaries

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6

Lets say I have 2 dictionaries:

```
dict_a = {'01A': 'X', '02B': 'V', '03C': 'AE'}
dict_b = {'01A': 'V', '02B': 'D', '03C': 'X'}
```

They essentially have the same keys. What I want is this:

```
dict_c = {'01A': ['X', 'V'], '02B': ['V', 'D'], '03C': ['AE', 'X']}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that, the one could be using `defaultdict` from `collections` something like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_a = {'01A': 'X', '02B': 'V', '03C': 'AE'}
dict_b = {'01A': 'V', '02B': 'D', '03C': 'X'}
d = defaultdict(list)
for d1, d2 in dict_a.items() + dict_b.items():
    d[d1].append(d2)
print(dict(d))
```